# Earth to space without using confessional engines

Tags: rocket-science, propulsion

Let's say we had a source of almost unlimited electric energy comparable to the volume and weight of today's orbital rockets. Is there a known propulsion engine that can take such vehicle from the earth's surface all the way to space?

Comment: What's a confessional engine? Do you mean *conventional* engine?

Comment: Welcome to the Physics.SE community.